# Trying to get a Button to change a Text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a button and want it to increase the value of x until it is 5, while displaying its value in the text box. I'm not quite sure why it won't work. The program just hangs when I run it.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()  
mybutton = Button(root,text="Push me to increase x!")                                     
mybutton.pack()                                     

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello!")
text.pack()

x = 0

def max():
    text.insert(END, "x is too big!")

def show():
    text.insert(END, "x is ", x)
    x += 1

while x < 6:
    mybutton.configure(command=show)
mybutton.configure(command=max)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hangs beacause this while loop is infnit:

```
while x < 6:
    mybutton.configure(command=show)
```

You are not increasing the value of x here. So it never reaches 6. I think that you are after something like this at the end:

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()  
mybutton = Button(root,text="Push me to increase x!")                                     
mybutton.pack()                                     

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "Hello!")
text.pack()

x = 0

def max():
    text.insert(END, "\nx is too big!")

def show():
    global x

    if x  == 6:
        max()
        return

    text.insert(END, "\nx is {}".format(x))
    x += 1



mybutton.configure(command=show)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't it run the `show` function which uses the `x+=1` statement?

Comment: GUI development is event driven, and the "actions" of the program dont occur in a "normal" order as they appear. So your `show` function must be executed in a response to a click button event only.  The event triggers/calls the show function which increments the x, not a while loop. Here `mybutton.configure(command=show)` you just tell Tk, that show should be executed as a result of the button click. It is not called prior this by itself.

Comment: I think I follow. So button presses can only be tied to one function, but I can have that function behave in a way where it considers different paths depending on certain conditions - like you did with your `if` statement?

Comment: Yep. you can do whatever you want in a 'show' function.

Comment: Cool! One more question: what does the `{}` and `format(x)` do? Is it like regular text with %?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) you can get info about format.